# How to write parameterized oracle insert query?

Tags: c#, oracle

I am using oracle as my back end and i write insert query as follows, i don't know is it correct way are not,

```
insert into Emp_table (SL_NO,empane,empid,salaray) values(1,'sree',1002 ,:salary);
```

here in query i am calculating salary with stored procedure and getting as my out parameter salary so i has to pass that to my insert query so how can i write. if i write like as shown i am getting below errors

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 175:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

kindly help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming salary amount is 20000, You can try this code:

```
var commandText = "insert into Emp_table (SL_NO,empane,empid,salaray) values(:SL_NO,:empane,:empid,:salary)";

using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(commandText, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SL_NO", 1);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("empane", "sree");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("empid", 1002);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("salaray", 20000);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft [deprecated their Oracle provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7(v=vs.110).aspx) (System.Data.OracleClient) so use a third party provider such as [Oracle's Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).  The code example below is essentially the same as [FSX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12812758/88204), just without the convenience of the `AddWithValue` method.

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SL_NO", 1));
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("empane", "sree"));
```

Comment: Please note that you have written 'New OracleParameter' => 'n' shouldn't be in capital letter in the 'new' keyword.

Comment: Thanks, Nishanth. Converted from VB to C#.

Answer (score 2):

```
   strin sql= "insert into Emp_table (SL_NO,empane,empid,salaray) values(:SL_NO,:empane,:empid,:salary)";
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection)
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SL_NO", 1);
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("empane", "sree"));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(("empid", 1002));
    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(("salaray", 20000));
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: I get error while adding Zero. For ex: ("salary",0).. Salary is defined as NUMBER in Oracle. @AshishModi