# vb.net convert dd MMM yyyy to Date

Tags: vb.net, oracle, date

I have tree view with selected value as Date with format `DD MON YYYY`.

Now I want to Convert it into date and insert into oracle Database table.

Problem is that when i insert it into DB it Show Like this if date is `15 AUG 2013` and when inserted into db it shows like this `8/20/0015 1:00:00 PM`.

But I don't want this wrong value.I want to insert exact date format.

Here is My Code through which i am inserting into DB:

```
Dim dte As String = TreeView1.SelectedValue

Dim cmmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select count(*) from DIR_CHQAPP_SR where APP_DTE = '" & dte & "' and sta_flg=" & flg & "", con)
Dim no As Integer = cmmd.ExecuteScalar()
If no < 1 Then
    cmmd.CommandText = "insert into DIR_CHQAPP_SR (APP_DTE, APP_NO,STA_FLG) values ('" & dte & "',1," & flg & ")"
Else
    cmmd.CommandText = "update DIR_CHQAPP_SR set app_no = nvl(app_no,0)+1 where APP_DTE = '" & dte & "' and sta_flg = " & flg & ""
End If
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

Comment: Do not concatenate SQL strings use [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812634/how-to-write-parameterized-oracle-insert-query) - that will both solve your date issue and safeguard you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I used Like this But No effect on `cmmd.CommandText = "insert into DIR_CHQAPP_SR (APP_DTE, APP_NO,STA_FLG) values (:APP_DTE,1," & flg & ")"
                cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":APP_DTE", dte.ToString())`

Comment: I suggest you read up on [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) and associated functions (`TryParse`, `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact`) and about [date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) - these should be used in conjunction with parameters.

Comment: I did like this it working Now `cmmd.CommandText = "insert into DIR_CHQAPP_SR (APP_DTE, APP_NO,STA_FLG) values (to_date('" & dte & "','dd/mm/yyyy'),1," & flg & ")"`

Comment: That is still open to SQL Injection. And the format you are using doesn't seem to match the format you say you have, so I can't see why you expect it to work either.

Comment: So What should i Do according to You.while As U Say With parameterized sense it didn't work

Comment: Didn't work is extremely vague. The link I put shows how to use parameters on a query - is that what you did?

Comment: Like other says, use Parameters, this will remove your problem if your variable is already a Datetime and will reduce the chance os SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I 100% agree with Oded, but to answer your question, if you use the function TO_DATE() that should solve your immediate problem.

```
cmmd.CommandText = "insert into DIR_CHQAPP_SR (APP_DTE, APP_NO,STA_FLG) values (TO_DATE('" & dte & "', 'DD MON YYYY'),1," & flg & ")"
```

To re-iterate - this is the WRONG way to insert data.

Comment: A better choice it to parse the string into a `DateTime` and pass that as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correct formatting for the date. Use dd MMM yyyy instead of DD MON YYYY and try.