# ORA-01843: not a valid month - issue on second pc

Tags: c#, oracle, date, datetime

On my pc (Win7) the statement is running without error. If I copy the c# .exe to a server (Win2012 server) where the program should finally run then I get the error

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

I read a csv-file and insert it into a oracle-db with the statement

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (DATUM, ...) VALUES('" + dr[0].ToString() + "',..."')";
```

`dr[0].ToString()` has the value `"01.06.2016"`

The column `DATUM` is type `DATE` in the oracle-db.

I debugged the code with a messagebox and get this result:

[image]

I can't see any difference between those two statements, the left one from the server is calling the error when I execute `int rowsupdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

I already compared the region settings and they are the same (german) on both systems. What else could cause the problem? Thanks

Part for filling the `Datatable` (source for `dr`):

```
StreamReader oStreamReader = new StreamReader(Zielverzeichnis + Dateiname, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); //nach, für Umlaute

                    DataTable dtCSV_Import = null;
                    int RowCount = 0;
                    string[] ColumnNames = null;
                    string[] oStreamDataValues = null;
                    //using while loop read the stream data till end
                    while (!oStreamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        String oStreamRowData = oStreamReader.ReadLine().Trim();
                        if (oStreamRowData.Length > 0)
                        {
                            oStreamDataValues = oStreamRowData.Split(';');
                            //Bcoz the first row contains column names, we will poluate 
                            //the column name by
                            //reading the first row and RowCount-0 will be true only once
                            if (RowCount == 0)
                            {
                                RowCount = 1;
                                ColumnNames = oStreamRowData.Split(';');
                                dtCSV_Import = new DataTable();

                                //using foreach looping through all the column names
                                foreach (string csvcolumn in ColumnNames)
                                {
                                    DataColumn oDataColumn = new DataColumn(csvcolumn.ToUpper(), typeof(string));

                                    //setting the default value of empty.string to newly created column
                                    oDataColumn.DefaultValue = string.Empty;

                                    //adding the newly created column to the table
                                    dtCSV_Import.Columns.Add(oDataColumn);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //creates a new DataRow with the same schema as of the oDataTable            
                                DataRow oDataRow = dtCSV_Import.NewRow();

                                //using foreach looping through all the column names
                                //Prüfen was kleiner ist, Spalten aus XML oder tatsächliche Spalten in der CSV -> sonst Fehler [i]
                                if (oStreamDataValues.Length < ColumnNames.Length)
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < oStreamDataValues.Length; i++)
                                    {
                                        oDataRow[ColumnNames[i]] = oStreamDataValues[i] == null ? string.Empty : oStreamDataValues[i].ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Length; i++)
                                    {
                                        oDataRow[ColumnNames[i]] = oStreamDataValues[i] == null ? string.Empty : oStreamDataValues[i].ToString();
                                    }
                                }

                                //adding the newly created row with data to the oDataTable       
                                dtCSV_Import.Rows.Add(oDataRow);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //close the oStreamReader object
                    oStreamReader.Close();
                    //release all the resources used by the oStreamReader object
                    oStreamReader.Dispose();
```

Comment: Never rely on implicit casting. This depends on the NLS settings that are used for the session. Instead always provide format explicitly: to_date(stringval,'dd-mm-yyyy')

Comment: What is `dr` exactly? Is it a data reader? Instead of string concatenation, why don't you cast it to `DateTime` (I assume it is `object` ) and add it with a parameterized query? And why you tagged with `mysql`?

Comment: You did compare the table definition on both systems as well, don't you? Would you mind adding it here?

Comment: @micklesh `to_date` did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @SonerGönül `dr` is a `DataRow`. I'm still learning so thanks for the hint

Comment: @katz If so, how do you fill that DataRow exactly? Can you show that part as well?

Comment: @katz great if it worked. Please consider accepting MT0's answer, apart from to_date he also covers other options

Comment: @SonerGönül I updated my question with the code

Comment: Why are you storing `DATUM` (date) and `ZEIT` (time) columns? Merge the two and store it all in one `DATE` column - dates **always** have a time component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are inserting values into a date column and try to insert a string value then Oracle will implicitly call `TO_DATE()` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask. If this format mask does not match then you will get an exception.

Session parameters can be set by individual users within their sessions - so if user Alice has the expected parameters this does not mean that user Bob will have the same parameters and the identical query you are using will not work as you are relying on implicitly casting values. Or even worse, Bob has the expected parameters today and then tomorrow decided that he would prefer his dates formatted as `DD-MON-YYYY` and changes his `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and suddenly, without changing your code, everything breaks and you are going to have a very bad time debugging the error.

If you want to insert a date then either:

1. Pass it as a bind variable (the best option) without converting it to a string; or
2. Use date literals (i.e. `DATE '2016-06-01'`); or
3. Use `TO_DATE()` with a specified format mask (i.e. `TO_DATE( '" + dr[0].ToString() + "', 'DD.MM.YYYY' )`).

You can read about [bind variables in the Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/building_odp.htm#CEGCGDAB) or in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812634/how-to-write-parameterized-oracle-insert-query).