# missing expression in Insert Query Using vb.net With Oracle Parameter

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am trying to Insert record Using Oracle Parameter But its  Give Missing Expression Exception. How Can i use another method for Insert Data into Database.

```
 Using conn As New OracleConnection(Constr)
            conn.Open()
            lTrans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

            msql = "INSERT INTO RJN_ENQ_ITEMS "
            msql = msql & "(TRANS_ID,TRANS_ITEM_ID,TAG_NO,PRD_CODE,KARAT,METAL_COLOR,  PIECES, GRS_WEIGHT,NET_WEIGHT,APP_USER_ID,TRANS_STATUS,PRICE,TOTAL_AMOUNT, TOTAL_WT,IMAGE_FILE_NAME) "
            msql = msql & "VALUES (@TRANS_ID,@TRANS_ITEM_ID, @TAG_NO,@PRD_CODE, @KARAT,@METAL_COLOR, @PIECES, @GRS_WEIGHT, @NET_WEIGHT,@APP_USER_ID,@TRANS_STATUS,@PRICE,@TOTAL_AMOUNT,@TOTAL_WT,@IMAGE_FILE_NAME);"


            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(msql, conn)





            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TRANS_ID", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TRANS_ID"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TRANS_ITEM_ID", ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TRANS_ITEM_ID"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TAG_NO", Session("CART_TAG_NO").ToString)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRD_CODE", Session("CART_TAG_NO").ToString)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@KARAT", drpkarat.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@METAL_COLOR", drpkartcolor.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PIECES", Val(txtpieces.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GRS_WEIGHT", Val(lblproductweight.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NET_WEIGHT", Val(changedkaratweight))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@APP_USER_ID", Val(gLogUserId))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TRANS_STATUS", 0)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRICE", Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState("OriginalPrice")))
            If Not IsNothing(ViewState("FinalAmount")) Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TOTAL_AMOUNT", Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState("FinalAmount")))
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TOTAL_AMOUNT", Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState("OriginalPrice")))
            End If
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TOTAL_WT", Val(lblproductweight.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IMAGE_FILE_NAME", (ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("IMAGE_FILE_NAME")))

            Dim res As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If res <= 0 Then
                lTrans.Rollback()

                Exit Sub
            End If

            lTrans.Commit()

End Using
```

Please Give Appropriate Suggestion for my code

Thanks In advance

Comment: I don't really use Oracle so I'm not sure but I don't think it supports `@` as a parameter prefix. You should check that out. I have a feeling it uses `:`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write parameterized oracle insert query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812634/how-to-write-parameterized-oracle-insert-query)