# How to insert image in oracle database in c# .net application

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

When i tried to insert, the error '*not enough values*' appears.

```
public int CreateAdmin( string product_name, string quality, string quantity, string price, string product_image)
{            
    string connectionString = "User Id=hr;Password=hr;Data Source=localhost:1521/xe";

    OracleConnection orc = new OracleConnection();
    orc.ConnectionString = connectionString; //assign connection
    //OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
    orc.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();//object of command
    cmd.Connection = orc;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // declare command type

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Product values( :b, :c, :d, :a, :p)";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", product_name); //add paramenter
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@c", quality);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@d", quantity);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", price);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p", product_image);

    //da.InsertCommand = cmd;
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    orc.Close();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error message

Comment: what happens if you change all the parameter adds to be Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("paramname", paramvalue)); such as Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("a", price));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write parameterized oracle insert query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812634/how-to-write-parameterized-oracle-insert-query)

Answer (score 1):

Your paramnames are wrong, they need to be named as the one you set in params - you use `:a` in the command and `@a` when setting the parameter. Parameter start with `@` (for SqlServer) or `:` (for OracleServer).

If your table has more columns than those 5 you have to provide them as well, else the db does not know where to put the given parameters. (an auto-inc ID additionally is fine, if thats your 6th column it will work).

```
public int CreateAdmin (string product_name, string quality, string quantity, string price, string product_image)
{
  string connectionString = "User Id=hr;Password=hr;Data Source=localhost:1521/xe";

  using (var orc = new OracleConnection (connectionString))
  {
    using (var cmd = orc.CreateCommand ())
    {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // declare command type

      // Product has exactly 5 or 5 + 1 auto-inc ID column, else provide the
      // column names as well: 
      // insert into Product ( name,qual,quant,price,img ) values( :b, :c, :d, :a, :p)";
      cmd.CommandText = "insert into Product values( :b, :c, :d, :a, :p)";

      cmd.Parameters.Add (":b", product_name); //add paramenter
      cmd.Parameters.Add (":c", quality);
      cmd.Parameters.Add (":d", quantity);
      cmd.Parameters.Add (":a", price);
      cmd.Parameters.Add (":p", product_image);

      //da.InsertCommand = cmd;
      int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();

      return i;
    }
  }
}
```

I changed your code to benefit from `using(var orc = new OracleConnection()) { .... }`-pattern with IDisposables - it auto-close/disposes your connection (same for command) on leaving the scope.

---

Edited due to comment by [Wernfried-Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit):

Oracle needs `:` (`@` is for SqlServer) - this answer [how-to-write-parameterized-oracle-insert-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812634/how-to-write-parameterized-oracle-insert-query) supports it - it even uses parameter names without `:` - so perhaps parameternames are just inserted by "order" instead of "by name"

Comment: I think `@` is for SQL-Server. For Oracle it must be `:` (in both, the SQL string and the parameter name)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for pointing it out - the linked answer omits the : in the parametername though.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have more columns in your `Product` table than you give in your values list. Explicitly give column names:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();//object of command
cmd.Connection = orc;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; // declare command type

// explicitly add column names
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Product (product_name, quality, quantity, price, product_image) values( :b, :c, :d, :a, :p)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(":b", product_name); //add paramenter
cmd.Parameters.Add(":c", quality);
cmd.Parameters.Add(":d", quantity);
cmd.Parameters.Add(":a", price);
cmd.Parameters.Add(":p", product_image);
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please change the column names in the above code to match your column names in your table. Let us know if that worked for you.

---

**Edit**

As stated by [Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner) in his well-written answer, the parameter name placeholders had to be the same in the CommandText and when adding the parameters to the command. When using `OracleCommand`, the placeholder needs to be `:` rather than `@` as stated in the [MSDN OracleCommand.Parameters page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for saving an image to your DB:

1. Convert your image to Base64 and save the output string to your DB
2. Save your image as a file on your server and save the path of this image to your DB (Recommended)